# What's the common name for the inverse of the lerp function?

Tags: function, naming-conventions, terminology, inverse, linear-interpolation

The function lerp() is a common function in programming languages:

```
lerp(a, b, t) = a + t * (b - a).
```

Now for very many situatons I have an inverse function:

```
fraction(x, a, b) = (x - a) / (b - a).
```

This function is built so that

```
lerp(a, b, fraction(x, a, b)) == x
```

and

```
fraction(lerp(a, b, t), a, b) == t
```

However I'm not happy with the name "fraction". Is there a common name for this function?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I'll also add that I like naming the `t` parameter “ratio” instead of “time” because it's often used as a ratio of one part to another part (so it's technically not the ratio but fraction part of the ratio).  So I've been leaning in recent years towards names like `decudeRatio()` or `ratioOf()` or `proportionFrom()` (“proportion“ is another name I like despite not fitting the math definition exactly).  This can be really clean in modern languages with named args, resulting in calls like `ratio(of: 3.5, in: 0.0...10.0)` or `(3.5).proportion(within: 0.0...10.0)`.

Comment: My library has prel (x, xLo, xHi) returning 0 to 1. Also lerpxlh (yLo, yHi, x, xLo, xHi) returning a y value proportionate as x within xLo to xHi.

Answer (score 14):

#### GLSL

GLSL's built-in functions include:

[`mix()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mix.xhtml), which works like your `lerp()` function.
[`smoothstep()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/smoothstep.xhtml), which works like your inverse-lerp function combined with hermite smoothing and a `x = clamp(x, 0.0, 1.0)`.

You could consider the name **`linearstep()`** for your implementation.

#### Unity Engine

Unity's API includes:

[`Lerp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)/[`LerpUnclamped()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpUnclamped.html)
[**`InverseLerp()`**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html), which does exactly what your inverse-lerp function does.

---

*Note: I wouldn't use the name `fraction()`— it seems that it would be easily confused with [`fract()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/fract.xhtml)/[`frac()`](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/frac.html), which do something completely different.*